# I cant figure this output when calling function(list index out of range)

Tags: python

I cant figure out this output.Im passing at p the list mapa as argument with positions of empty pos list. Ball should exist also because im passing it aswell in p function

```
mapa={1:['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
           2:['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
           3:['.','.','.','.','.','.']}

pos=[]

ball='o'
vacio='.'

def pintar():
for i in range(1,len(mapa)+1):
    print("".join(mapa[i]))

def bola():
for i in range(1,len(mapa)+1):
    if ball in mapa[i]:
        global pos
        x_pos=1
        pos.append(x_pos)

def refresh():
 pintar()
 bola()

def p(dic,inst_replace,inst_player):
(dic[pos[0]]).pop(pos[1])
(dic[pos[0]]).insert(pos[1],inst_replace)
(dic[pos[0]]).pop(pos[1]+1)
(dic[pos[0]]).insert(pos[1]+1,inst_player)

while True:
 p(mapa,ball,vacio)
 refresh()
 print(pos)
```

Comment: Can you include the `Traceback`?

Comment: fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is the `pos[0]` in line 1 of `p()`. You've defined `pos` as an empty list near the the top of the file, and you haven't called `bola()`, so it has no 0th element. The error is letting you know that you've tried to look up a list index that doesn't exist.

I think you want to switch the order of your calls to `refresh()` and `p()` in the While loop, so that `bola()` gets called before you do lookups in `pos`.

Comment: Im callin bola() at while loop in refresh function

Comment: but you're doing so /after/ you call p, as I pointed out in my second paragraph. that's why it's breaking, you need to call refresh first.

Comment: Im just trying make a list where the dots are figured as empty places. The ball should move forward along that list. My idea is seeing the effect of that ball moving in a single output line

Comment: yes, i know. I'm telling you that to fix your bug, you need to switch the order of `p(mapa,ball,vacio)` and `refresh()` in your code.

Comment: That should certainly fix the immediate problem you posted about, there may be others. If it does, please click the checkmark to accept the answer :)

Comment: I didnt try yet because im a but busy but i cant understand the order you explained.  Calling p() function first makes an instance of ball

Comment: I tried what you told me but I still have the same output. List index out of range

Comment: Oh, well, yeah – it's because the ball isn't actually in `mapa`, so nothing ever gets added to pos. Additionally, I don't think there's any way for /two/ things to get added to it, so pos[1] is always going to fail.